# php - remove indexes of an aray if they have the same value

Tags: php, arrays, unique

How can i make the values of such an array unique.

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => pen [2] => perfume [3] => pen) )`

as there is pen twice i would like it to be deleted in this way :

`( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => pen [2] => perfume) )`

OR

`( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => perfume [2] => pen) )`

and i would like it to apply for any length.

thanks for your help

Comment: By the way I tried array_unique but did not work, was still returning me the same array. Maybe i didn't use it in a good way.

Comment: `array_unique($array[0]);` Your array is nested, either loop over it and apply array_unique to each set or just the first item if there's only ever one. http://codepad.org/wyoob0z2

Answer (score 2):

How about [array_flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) used twice:

```
$arr = Array(0 => wallet, 1 => pen, 2 => perfume, 3 => pen);
$arr = array_flip(array_flip($arr));
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => wallet
    [3] => pen
    [2] => perfume
)
```

If you want to renumbered the indexes, add this ligne after:

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: That is a brilliant solution! I would have never guessed that behavior. That is partially PHP's fault for bad naming practices for its functions.

Comment: @M42 i have to admit would have never think of this, but i would like the array index to be 1,2,3,..

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to select a unique value you need to pass the array that you want to compare the values, I am assuming you passed the main array, you need to pass the array where the problem is found which is in your case the index `0` of an array

```
$result = array_unique($input[0]);
```

`$input` will have an array of unique values so pen will not be 2

if you need to delete any duplicated values in the array you can do this.

```
$input[0] = array_unique($input[0]);
```

if you need to reset the index you can use this

```
$new_index = array_values($input[0]);
print_r($new_index);
```

Comment: works but problem with the index, it does: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => wallet [1] => perfume [3] => pen) )` and i need it to be always 1,2,3 so for later use

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = array ();

foreach ($array as $row) 
             array_push($tmp,array_unique($row));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for multi dimensopnal array

```
$res  = array();
foreach($your_array as $key=>$val){
  $res[$key] = array_unique($val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```